# When a value is selected from the combobox nothing is being shown

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am declaring a combobox like:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RenderableSeriesList, Mode=OneWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Tag" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRenderableSeries}" />
```

TheRenderableSeriesList is a ObservableCollection of BaseRenderableSeries.  BaseRenderableSeries is a abstract class which contains the Tag property and the Tag property is a object.  The TheRenderableSeriesList object is filled with classes that all inherit from BaseRenderableSeries.

Everything works right except that it doesn't show the selected item.  When something is selected the SelectedRenderableSeries property does point to the correct one.  Also the list is correct when the combobox drops down.

I am a bit baffled as to why this...

EDIT:
After further investigating this might be a bug in WPF itself.

If you try to Bind from the Tag property when it is coming from the ContentControl it doesn't seem to bind correctly.

Here is some code that demonstrates:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void AddItems()
    {
        TestObjects = new ObservableCollection<BaseTestObject>();
        TestObjects.Add(new TestObject("one"));
        TestObjects.Add(new TestObject("two"));

        TestObjects.Add(new TestObject2("22two22"));
        TestObjects.Add(new TestObject2("t22hree222"));

        TestObjects.Add(new TestObject("three"));
        TestObjects.Add(new TestObject("four"));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<BaseTestObject> _testObjects = new ObservableCollection<BaseTestObject>();

    public ObservableCollection<BaseTestObject> TestObjects
    {
        get { return _testObjects; }
        set
        {
            _testObjects = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("TestObjects");
        }
    }

    private BaseTestObject _testObject;

    public BaseTestObject TestObject
    {
        get { return _testObject; }
        set
        {
            _testObject = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("TestObject");
        }
    }
}

// gets the Tag object property from FrameworkElement
// using FrameworkElement works....but ContentControl doesn't
public class BaseTestObject : ContentControl
{
    //public object Tag { get; set; }
    public string MyName { get; set; }
}

public class TestObject : BaseTestObject
{
    string Name1 { get; set; }

    public TestObject(string name)
    {
        Name1 = name;
        Tag = name;
    }
}

public class TestObject2 : BaseTestObject
{
    string Name2 {get; set;}

    public TestObject2(string name)
    {
        Name2 = name;
        Tag = name;
    }
}


    <ComboBox Height="40" Width="250" ItemsSource="{Binding TestObjects, Mode=TwoWay}"           DisplayMemberPath="Tag" SelectedItem="{Binding TestObject, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you're saying that your bound property updates correctly when the selection changes, but the change is not displaying on-screen. In order for items on-screen to update, you have to call your NotifyPropertyChanged method when the property updates. This will signal to the UI that a property has been set to a new value, and any control bound to that value should be refreshed.

Comment: He said that SelectedRenderableSeries does not point to right value. In your suggestion value is right and the goal would be to let know UI about change.

Comment: @Maximus No, he says it *does* point to the correct one. It just doesn't show up.

Comment: You are correct furkle.  It seems to have something to do with binding to a ContentControl's Tag property.